# chart library to display data in a web page in given format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, highcharts

What chart library I should use to display data in following formats, as shown in images below. Is it possible to show such format with HighCharts? Does google chart supports combination of bubbles and lines?

[image]

Comment: For me these charts looks like simple bubble charts with some custom drawings (like dashed lines, circles etc.). In Highcharts should be easily possible to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend a custom made solution based on SVG.

Look at jquery svg http://keith-wood.name/svg.html for a good library to have svg generated on the fly.

you simply "draw" on a svg canvas...

```
var svg = $('#svgcanvas').svg('get'); 
svg.circle(130, 75, 50, {fill: 'none', stroke: 'blue', strokeWidth: 3});
```